# Subscribing to an observable doesn't execute properly

Tags: angular

**UPDATE:**
I was able to solve my observable problem by following a blog post written by Cory Rylan [Blog Post](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-observable-data-services)

I am trying to subscribe to an observable of type Theme.  When the theme changes, I need to inform app.component about the change.

So I have this in the themes.service:

```
setTheme(theme: string) {
    var ft = this.findTheme(this.selectedTheme);
    this.selectedTheme = theme;
    var d = document.getElementById('themeStyleSheet')
    d.setAttribute('href', this.getThemePath(theme));
    this.setNewTheme(ft);
}

setNewTheme(theme: Theme): void {
    console.log("setting new theme");
    this.theme = theme;
    this.subject.next(theme);
}

getNewTheme(): Observable<Theme> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
}
```

In my app.component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    private items: MenuItem[];
    appPageHeaderDivStyle: {};
    selectedTheme: Theme;
    errorMessage: string;
    //loggedIn: LoggedIn;

    constructor(
        private appMenuService: AppMenuService,
         private themeService: ThemeService)
        // private loginService: LoginService)
         { 
    }
ngOnInit() {

  console.log('going to get new theme');
  this.themeService.getNewTheme()
    .subscribe(
    theme => this.selectedTheme = theme,
    error => {
      this.errorMessage = error
      debugger;
    },
    () => this.completeGetNewTheme()
  );

  this.themeService.setTheme("Pepper-Grinder");
  this.items = this.appMenuService.getNoLoginMenu();
}

completeGetNewTheme() {
  console.log("in complete new theme");
  this.appPageHeaderDivStyle = this.themeService.getAppPageHeaderDivStyle();
}
```

The themes sevice is injected with the declarations in the shared.module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule, RouterModule ],
  declarations: [Menubar, Galleria, InputText, Panel, Button, Dropdown, Dialog], //, Checkbox, Calendar, RadioButton, SelectButton, DataTable, Column, Dropdown, Accordion, AccordionTab], //, ControlErrorMessagesComponent ],
  exports:      [ CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule, RouterModule, Menubar, Galleria, InputText, Panel, Button, Dropdown, Dialog] //Menubar, Galleria, InputText, Checkbox, Panel, Calendar, RadioButton, SelectButton, DataTable, Column, Button, Dropdown, Accordion, AccordionTab ]
})

export class SharedModule {
//
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [SettingsService, AppMenuService, AuthorizationService, LoginService, RegisterService, ThemeService, ValidationService, NutritionixService]
    };
  }
}
```

I have traced it through the setNewTheme method which fires just fine, however, the subscribe never activates.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you working with the same instance of theme.service throughout?  Where do you create the service/define your provider for injection?

Comment: I updated my original post to show the shared module.

Comment: And so you import the SharedModule into your other modules.  In your top level module you do:  `providers: [ ... SharedModule.forRoot() ...]` and in the other modules you just do `imports: [... SharedModule ...]` with no subsequent provider line?

Comment: Yes, That's true...